# Quarkus exception logging limit

Tags: quarkus, error-logging

I'm trying to configure quarkus to log exceptions with limited or no stacktrace, just the exception class and message.
I've tried changing the property:

- `quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n`: logs message, exception and stacktrace
- `quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n`: same as previous
- `quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%n`: does not log anything related to the exception.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do this currently (as JBoss Logmanager does not have this option). Mind opening an issue asking for the feature?